# Spill the metaphorical beans?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I was reading a comic book and ran into this phrase. Is there any difference between 'spill the beans' and 'spill the metaphorical beans'? here is the context.

**Talk show host:** "But seriously, Reed. *Spill the metaphorical beans*. What gives with Attilan?"
**Reed:** "Well, Attilan's a riddle wrapped up in an enigma inside a conundrum. I can say that they are a very remarkable people"

Would that mean **"Tell me what you think about this in metaphorical manner"**? I want to make sure what the difference is. Can anybody help me to understand?

Comment: There is no difference.'Spill the beans' is a well-known metaphor, so adding 'metaphorical' is just for style because the host thinks it sounds better. It is somewhat redundant, unless Reed is sat with a container of beans in his lap.

Comment: Wow, thank you for enlightening me! <3

Comment: *Proverbial* is also commonly inserted, as in *spill the proverbial beans*.

Comment: The alternate meaning might be expressed as _Spill the beans, metaphorically._ Although I think most would still interpret that as equivalent to the original. To really get the point across, you'd probably have to use something like your long-winded version.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference between ***spill the beans*** and ***spill the metaphorical beans*** is that one employs an obvious idiom whereas the other assumes the listener is learned enough to know what ***metaphorical*** means but ignorant to the non-literal nature of the expression ***spill the beans***.

In an instance where there is some legitimate potential for confusion, such as if you were a teacher telling a young student to ***pull their socks up***, it might warrant the extra emphasis. In the context of a talk show host it's just using extra words for the sake of filling space or trying to look intelligent.